# Intellij IDEA search functionality always stops working

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13

The `find in path` search works on newly cloned/downloaded repos. But I notice after a few days, all search functionality in the IDE just stops working. Searching for anything string turns up 0 results in `project`, `module`, `directory` paths. Anyone else experience this? It's infinitely infuriating T.T

OS: Mac
Version: Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2020
Settings: only default

Comment: I've been using Intelij for last ~7y and didn't notice this problem once. Did you try to reset settings or reinstall it without importing preferences?

Comment: Try with custom plugins disabled. Also, try the version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/ Check if there are any `ERROR` in [IDE logs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#logs-directory).

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to invalidate caches via *File | Invalidate Caches / Restart* option.

It's a known issue [IDEA-266391](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-266391) and you can update IntelliJ IDEA to the 2021.1.1 version with the fix.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out this is happening whenever I change branches. So your suggested soln above works well. thanks!